# binding IEnumerable data to a gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi I've searched everywhere for some example code for this, but I can't figure out how to bind data returned from a function that looks like this to a gridview or dataset.

```
Public Function GetCompanyList() As IEnumerable(Of BusinessUser)
    Return (From companyList In CorporateLists
            Select companyList.User).Distinct()
End Function
```

I know that 'BusinessUser' has 4 properties:

- userID
- firstName
- lastName
- emailAddr

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you have to try with this way..

```
GridView1.DataSource = GetCompanyList()
GridView1.DataBind()
```

For more Refer this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx)